# What is a starter cell?

Tags: neuroscience, neurophysiology, neuroanatomy, neurology, neurotransmitter

I am reading the paper [Cooperative Subnetworks of Molecularly Similar
Interneurons in Mouse Neocortex](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0896627316001744) and a term "starter cell" apears there (page 6):

> This yielded tissue sections where SOM or
>   VIP **starter cells** carry both nucleus-localized GFP and cytoplasmic mCherry

Does anyone know what a starter cell is?
(I couldn't find it on the web)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nice question - this terminology isn't referring to a special type of cell or anything, but to a peculiarity of the technique they are using.

They are labeling a subset of cells with rabies virus; rabies then travels in retrograde fashion to presynaptic cells, and labels those as well.

The "starter cells" are those initially infected cells, where the tracing "starts." [This reference](http://www.jneurosci.org/content/35/24/8979.short) more explicitly states this terminology, and talks about the technique extensively, I would strongly recommend it for helping to understand the paper you are reading.

Comment: I understand now.... I will also read the article you reffer to. Thank you for your clarification!